# Get column value from tagdata from matrikon OPC server to visual studio logging application, C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opc

I want to acquire quality and status as well as value from Matrikon OPC server. I am going to put the values from my visual basic logging application to a table in SQL server so the method `ShowOpcData` is returning a string which is a query for a stored procedure

When running the application i get error at:

> string value = dataSocket.Data.Attributes["Value"].Value.ToString();
>   (and all the other dataSocket.Data.Attributes....

Here is the code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data.SqlTypes;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using NationalInstruments;
    using NationalInstruments.Net;

    namespace DATALOGGING_SYSTEM
    {
        //READ VALUES FROM OPC SERVER
        public class readFromOpc
        {
            DataSocket dataSocket = new DataSocket();
            public string showOpcData()
            {
                string tagUrl;

                //SPECIFYING OPC URL:
                tagUrl = "opc://localhost/Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1/Bucket Brigade.Real4";

                if (dataSocket.IsConnected)
                    dataSocket.Disconnect();

                //CONNECT TO THE OPC SERVER USING AccessMode.Read VIA TAGURL
                dataSocket.Connect(tagUrl, AccessMode.Read);
                dataSocket.Update();

                string Value = dataSocket.Data.Attributes["Value"].Value.ToString();
                string Status =dataSocket.Data.Attributes["Status"].Value.ToString();
                string Quality = dataSocket.Data.Attributes["Quality"].Value.ToString();
                string TagId = "1";

                string query = "EXECUTE StoreValue '" + Value + "','" + Status + "','" + Quality + "','" + TagId + "'";

                return query;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `i get error at: string value...` and what's the error?

Comment: The error states: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in NationalInstruments.Net.dll